# jQuery - Variable is being shared across instances

Tags: jquery, scope, jquery-plugins, multiple-instances

I'm making a image slider plugin which is working fine with single instance but when I have multiple instances on the page, the variables are being shared across these instances, especially `currentPosition`. How do I sandbox them and keep the instances isolated?

I've tried to piece it together with whatever tutorials I could find and also looked at similar questions on SO but they didn't help. Here's the code:

```
var slider = $('.slider').mySlider();
```

...

```
;(function ($) {
  var defaults = {
    auto: false,
    delay: 4000,
    controls: true,
    controlsPosition: 'inside', //inside, outside, neighbors
    prevHtml: '<i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>',
    nextHtml: '<i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>',
    width: 70,
    transitionSpeed: 400,
    onLoad: function() {},
    onSlideEnd : function() {}
  };

  var mySliderInit = function (el, options) {
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options || {}),
    el = $(el);
    el.wrap('<div class="mySlider-outerwrapper"><div class="mySlider-wrapper"></div></div>');

    var outerWrapper = el.closest('.mySlider-outerwrapper'),
    wrapper = el.closest('.mySlider-wrapper');

    var numSlides = el.find('li').length,
    numElements = numSlides+4,
    wrapperWidth = wrapper.width(),
    slideWidth = wrapperWidth*(settings.width)/100,
    sideWidth = wrapperWidth*((100 - settings.width)/2)/100;

    var slides = el.find('li');
    slides.width(slideWidth);

    //first move
    var index = 0;
    var slideMovement = wrapperWidth*settings.width/100;
    var firstMovement = currentPosition = -(slideWidth-sideWidth+slideWidth);
    el.css('transform', 'translateX('+(firstMovement)+'px)');

    if(settings.controls){
      outerWrapper.append('<a href="#" class="mySlider-nav mySlider-prev">'+settings.prevHtml+'</a>');
      outerWrapper.append('<a href="#" class="mySlider-nav mySlider-next">'+settings.nextHtml+'</a>');
    }

    function moveSlider(direction){
      if(direction == 'forward'){
        index++;
        currentPosition -= slideWidth;
      } else if(direction == 'backward'){
        index--;
        currentPosition += slideWidth;
      }
      $(slides[index+2]).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
      el.css('transform', 'translateX('+currentPosition+'px)');

    }

    outerWrapper.on('click', '.mySlider-next', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      moveSlider('forward');
    });

    outerWrapper.on('click', '.mySlider-prev', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      moveSlider('backward');
    });

    return this;
  };

  $.fn.mySlider = function (settings){
    return this.each(function(){
      new mySliderInit($(this), settings);
    });
  }

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: can you create a working fiddle, with 2 or 3 slideshow elements, so we can see how the code is working?

Comment: [Does this help](http://bwdmedia.in/slider/)? Try clicking Right arrow on first slider, then second. THe second will move two places.

Comment: well actually, a fiddle to play around would be better... but i have an idea. according to w3s javascript scope: `If you assign a value to a variable that has not been declared, it will automatically become a GLOBAL variable.` according to your console.log - your code seems to be working for the index variable, having different values depending on the slider you click on. the currentPosition variable is not declared, but directly assigned a value. try to insert a line `var currentPosition` at the area of your code, as the `var index = 0;`

Comment: Ahh. That was it. That solved the problem. Thank you so much. Put it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to w3s javascript scope: `If you assign a value to a variable that has not been declared, it will automatically become a GLOBAL variable.`

according to your console.log - your code seems to be working for the index variable, having different values depending on the slider you click on. the currentPosition variable is not declared, but directly assigned a value. try to insert a line var currentPosition at the area of your code, as the `var index = 0;`

--- not part of the solution ---

some years ago, i found a really simple idea for a self build slide show. i used that for an image carousel, where only one image is shown. but maybe you can figure out to adapt this to your slideshow.

the idea of this carousel was, to simply move the first element to the end or the last element to the first position, depending on the direction, you went.
in my example, there are no controls, but a simple forward click event

```
$(".mySlideElement").on("click", function(){ //the click event on any slide element
var myParent = $(this).parent(); //get the parent of your current set of slide elements
var myElements = myParent.find(".mySlideElement"); //get all slide elements
$(myElements).first().appendTo(myParent); //take the first one and move it to the end
})
```

i build a small jsfiddle, here: https://jsfiddle.net/6e9xk5wz/1/

Comment: Thanks errand but my goal is to learn to make a plugin and you helped with that a lot hahaha